# Rewards for score in sprite kit game xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

hi im making a game in which i can get the score with sklabelnode easily  even i made how to get rewards when user reaches 25 , 50 points and so on but when i reach 50 and >50 im  getting bronze only not silver and gold so on, where i made a mistake.

```
@implementation MyScene {
int _gameScore;
SKNode *_gameLayer;}

-(void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact



 SKSpriteNode *coin = nil;
    if (_gameScore >= 25) {

        coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bronze"];
    } else if (_gameScore >= 50) {

        coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"silver"];   
    }else if (_gameScore >= 100) {

        coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"gold"];   
    }
    else {
        //blank coin
        coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"noreward"];
    }

    if (coin != nil) {

        coin.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width/2, self.size.height/2 );
        coin.zPosition = 201;
         [coin setSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];

        [_gameLayer addChild:coin];
    }
```

Comment: when i'm adding if  to all rewards it showing only "noward"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you have it now, you'll see your "bronze" coin any time `_gameScore` is greater than or equal to `25`. Since `50` and `100` are also greater than `25` and your checks for them are *after* the check for `25`, you'll never see "silver" or "gold"

Since you're using `>=`, your checks should go from highest to lowest:

```
if (_gameScore >= 100) {

    coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"gold"];   
} else if (_gameScore >= 50) {

    coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"silver"];   
} else if (_gameScore >= 25) {

    coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bronze"];
} else {
    //blank coin
    coin = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"noreward"];
}
```